# Why does SQLAlchemy produce an insert with incorrect values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using the following classes and the test program at the bottom, I get a malformed Insert where the value for Application_Id is written as '(n,)', where 'n' s the value that have been inserted, i.e. if Application_Id is supposed to be 2, the value '(2,') is in it's place.

I haven't been able to find why this happens as, as far as I can see, there's no difference in how the other foreign key columns are handled.
(all imports excluded -- that's not the problem).

I'm using Python 3.4.4 and SQLAlchemy 1.1.5 on Windows 10 + Visual Studio 2015. Switching to another OS or IDE is not an option :-(

Timespan

```
class Timespan(Base):
    """

    """
    __tablename__ = 'timespan'
    def __init__(self, start, end, account, application, language):
        self.StartTime = start
        self.EndTime = end
        self.Account_Id = account
        self.Application_Id = application,
        self.Language_Id = language

    StartTime = Column(DateTime)
    EndTime = Column(DateTime)
    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    Account_Id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.Id'))
    Application_Id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('application.Id'))
    Language_Id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('language.Id'))
```

Application

```
class Application(Base):
    """

    """
    __tablename__ = 'application'
    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    Code = Column(String)
    Description = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, code, description):
        self.Code = code
        self.Description = description
```

Account

```
class Account(Base):
    """

    """

    __tablename__ = 'account'

    def __init__(self, uid, domain):
        self.MvidDomain = domain
        self.MvidUid = uid

    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    MvidUid = Column(Integer)
    MvidDomain = Column(String)
```

Language

```
class Language(Base):
    """

    """
    def __init__(self, description, code):
        self.Description = description
        self.Code = code

    __tablename__ = 'language'

    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    Description = Column(String)
    Code = Column(String)
```

Test program

```
class TimespanTest(TestCase):
    def test_insert(self):
        engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo = True)
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

        Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
        session = Session()
        application = Application(code = 'itw', description = 'desc')
        lang = Language(description = 'test language', code = 'da')
        account = Account(uid = 'test_user', domain = 'test_domain')

        session.add(lang)
        session.add(application)
        session.add(account)
        session.commit()

        print (lang.Id)
        print (application.Id)
        print (account.Id)

        timespan = Timespan(
                datetime.today(), datetime.today(),
                account = account.Id,
                application = application.Id,
                language = lang.Id)
        session.add(timespan)
        session.commit()
```

Debug output/Exception:

```
(sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type. 
[SQL: 'INSERT INTO timespan ("StartTime", "EndTime", "Account_Id", "Application_Id", "Language_Id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)']
[parameters: ('2017-01-24 08:29:23.447994', '2017-01-24 08:29:23.447994', 1, (1,), 1)]
```

The problems is in the second to last parameter, i.e. the value (1,), which should be just plain 1.

Comment: So what is the output of `print (application.Id)` a tuple or plain 1?

Comment: Just a plain 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problem in **Timespan** Class, Notice a **,** after  **=application,** remove this and work. Here is code having removed comma:-

```
class Timespan(Base):
    """

    """
    __tablename__ = 'timespan'
    def __init__(self, start, end, account, application, language):
        self.StartTime = start
        self.EndTime = end
        self.Account_Id = account
        self.Application_Id = application
        self.Language_Id = language

    StartTime = Column(DateTime)
    EndTime = Column(DateTime)
    Id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    Account_Id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.Id'))
    Application_Id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('application.Id'))
    Language_Id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('language.Id'))
```